# Issues with desctructor called twice in C++ class having 'has-a' relationship

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class A, which contains an object of another class B. This is a private object. However when I tried to access B's member variable using A's object, somehow B's desctructor is getting called. 
Not able to understand why B's destructor is getting called here?

Output of following code is:

```
In B ctor
In A ctor
10
In B dtor     <------ Why this ?
In A dtor
In B dtor
```

Code Sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    //Implementaion of B class
    class B
    {
    public:
        int bVal1;
        B::B(void)
        {
            cout << "In B ctor" << endl;
            bVal1 = 10;
        }
        B::~B(void)
        {
            cout << "In B dtor" << endl;
        }
    };

    //Implementaion of A class having private B's object ( composition )
    class A
    {
    private:
        B b;
    public:
        A::A(void)
        {
            cout << "In A ctor" << endl;
        }
        A::~A(void)
        {
            cout << "In A dtor" << endl;
        }
        B A::func2(void)
        {
            return b;

        }
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        A a;                                //ctor calling order : B followed by A
        cout << a.func2().bVal1 << endl;    //Why ADDITIONAL B's destructor is getting called here ???
        return 0;                           //dtor calling order : A followed by B
    }
```

My apologies for this long code.

Answer (score 3):

You function

```
B A::func2(void)
{
    return b;

}
```

returns a copy of object of type `B`. So you have a temporary local version in `main()` function. So the `A::b` object and the temporary `B` object both get destroyed, therefore you have 2 calls to `B::~B()`.

Your main() function is equivalent to this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;                                //ctor calling order : B followed by A
    B b = a.func2();
    cout << b.bVal1 << endl;    //Why ADDITIONAL B's destructor is getting called here ???
    return 0;                           //dtor calling order : b, followed by A::b followed by followed by a
}
```

Try writing it like this:

```
const B& A::func2(void)
{
    return b;
}
```

This will give you only 1 call of `B::~B()`.